# Gatsby Lifecycle API question relating to Create Node and Create Page

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to learn Gatsby by writing a plugin using the lifecycle API. I am using the Gatsby default starter and I put in my local plugin's `gatsby-node.js` some debug statements. Here's the output of `gatsby build`:

```
- creating node: [Site] children: []
- creating node: [Directory] children: []
- creating page: [/404/] json name [404-22d]
- creating page: [/] json name [index]
- creating page: [/page-2/] json name [page-2-fbc]
- creating node: [SitePage] path: [/404/] children: []
- creating node: [SitePage] path: [/] children: []
- creating node: [SitePage] path: [/page-2/] children: []
- creating page: [/404.html] json name [404-html-516]
- creating node: [SitePage] path: [/404.html] children: []
```

Here's my `gatsby-node.js` in my local plugin:

```
function onCreateNode({node, loadNodeContent}) {
  let message = `- creating node: [${node.internal.type}]`;
  if (node.path) {
    message += ` path: [${node.path}]`;
  }
  if (node.children) {
    message += " children: " + JSON.stringify(node.children);
  }
  if (node.owner) {
    message += ` owner: [${node.internal.owner}]`;
  }
  console.log(message);
}

function onCreatePage({page, actions}) {
  let message = `- creating page: [${page.path}] json name [${page.jsonName}]`;
  console.log(message);
}

exports.onCreateNode = onCreateNode;
exports.onCreatePage = onCreatePage;
```

I don't understand the followings:

1. Why are there two create page calls for 404, one for `/404/` and the other for `/404.html`?
2. It appears in the debug statements that create page is called before create node (see above where `creating page` precedes `creating node`). Why is that? Shouldn't it be the other way around? (maybe the callbacks are done in a different order?)
3. Ultimately, I don't fully understand the relationship between a node and a page. Is there a relationship?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Why are there two create page calls for 404, one for /404/ and the other for /404.html?

By default all gatsby generated pages, except for `index`, is put in a folder with a `index.html` file in it, i.e `my-domain.com/page1` will have a `page1` folder with `index.html` in it. Why? I'm guessing that if someone turns off javascript they'd still get the nice url (`my-domain.com/page1/` instead of `my-domain.com/page1.html`.

The reason why `404` is copied from `404/` to `404.html` is because

> many static site hosts expect site 404 pages to be named this. — [source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/445f5ff7508ab613967e18b32490e3feffd7730c/packages/gatsby/src/internal-plugins/prod-404/gatsby-node.js)

#### 2. It appears in the debug statements that create page is called before create node. Why is that?

This has tripped me off a few times too & I'm still not too sure why. The `createPages` api is definitely called after `sourceNodes`, so here's my guess: `onCreateNode` & `onCreatePage` are triggered asynchronously; however, gatsby will call these hooks of each individual plugin serially. Perhaps by the time it's your turn (your `gatsby-node.js` hooks will be called last), gatsby has already moved on to the next steps (again, just speculation).

Also, keep in mind that when `createPage` is run, gatsby doesn't actually write out the page with data, it just [keeps track of the page's metadata stuff](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-creation/).

Here's some helpful resouces:

- [Gatsby: behind the scenes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/behind-the-scenes/)
- [Gatsby: how apis are run](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/how-plugins-apis-are-run/#using-traceid-to-await-downstream-api-calls)

#### 3. Is there a relationship (between a node and a page)?

Not really. The user are the one who creates relationship between node and page by writing graphql queries that request data for a page.

By default, gatsby includes this [plugin for all site](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-page-creator), which turns files in `src/pages/` into pages. User'd still have to query the data for those pages themselves.

So except for the node created for each pages by the internal plugin [data bridge](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/internal-data-bridge/), there's no relationship between node & page.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Even though it did not fully answered my questions, it provided some reference materials for me to go over.